# delete child node with specific value in xml file

Tags: xml, xpath

Can anyone explain me why I cannot delete this childnode using this query. It gives me an error saying  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll. Additional information: The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("sample.xml");
        xDoc.RemoveChild(xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='ECMInstruction']/Property[@Id='2']/Lists[contains(ListName,'ws_Users')]"));
        xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
```

The xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
      <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
        <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
        <Property Id="1">
        </Property>
        <Property Id="2">
          <Lists>
            <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
             <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
          </Lists>
        </Property>
      </Class>
    </Root>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call RemoveChild directly on the node the one you're trying to remove is a child of? Not on the root node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An untested attempt:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("sample.xml");
var parent = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='ECMInstruction']/Property[@Id='2']/Lists");
var nodeToRemove = parent.SelectSingleNode("ListName[text() = 'ws_Users')]");
parent.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
```

Comment: yours has worked by selecting the node specifically with a text containing ws_Users and removing the parent from the statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this

```
Lists[contains(ListName,'ws_Users')]
```

your xml contains 2 child nodes named `ListName` of `Lists`. the first argument of contains() function should contain just a single item. Change that to:

```
Lists[ListName[contains(.,'ws_Users')]]
```

Comment: Please see this link (http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8ba0a0c1e4ee300d77e189e78b4a7899). It correctly selects the node that you want to delete.

Comment: i can see that but with my above statement it doesnt do nothing

Comment: I see, you want to remove `Lists` node and all it's children?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get parent node of the node to be removed and call `.RemoveChild()` from that parent node :

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("sample.xml");
var nodeTobeRemoved = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Class[@Name='ECMInstruction']/Property[@Id='2']/Lists/ListName[contains(.,'ws_Users')]");
nodeTobeRemoved.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeTobeRemoved);
xDoc.Save("sample.xml");
```

Comment: I tried yours but the problem is that it deletes the listname and its parent node which is lists. so all lists are deleted and i dont want that.

Comment: If that is what you want, the XPath should be like this : `//Class[@Name='ECMInstruction']/Property[@Id='2']/Lists/ListName[contains(.,'ws_Users')]`